# Remember 3 students who showed their homework last time

Tags: python-3.x

3 students who showed their homework last time. Every time this program is run, it should picks a new set of 3 students.

Comment: Can you provide the Question with some detail please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming students roll numbers are given

```
students_roll_number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

students_homework_showed = [3,4,5]
```

To get the students who didn't show their homework yet

```
students_homework_pending = [students_roll_number[i] for i in  range(len(students_roll_number)) if students_roll_number[i] not in students_homework_showed]
```

Output is

```
students_homework_pending = [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

now we pick 3 students from pending list

```
students_to_check = []
for i in range(3): 
    students_homework_showed.append(students_homework_pending[i])
    students_to_check.append(students_homework_pending[i])
```

New students to choose from

```
print("chosen student is : ", students_to_check)
```